# use-after-move POD parts of composite class with defaulted move ctor

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a class with non-POD and POD parts. Move constructor and move assignments are defaulted. Are the POD-parts of an instance of this class safe to use after a move?

```
#include <string>
struct A {
    std::string s = "foo";
    int i = 42;
};
A a;
A b = std::move(a);
int j = a.i; //OK or UB?
```

Is element-wise move/copy guaranteed (so this would be OK) or could a conforming implementation alter the POD parts (e.g., by swapping with a default-constructed object)?

Comment: Good question. But never even think about actually using *anything* after moving. It defeats the whole purpose of move semantics.

Comment: Iirc, primitive types are guaranteed to be treated as a copy so this particular example should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

The default move ctor simply does a move on each member (and base).

Moving a primitive type just copies it.

So this is well defined at that level.

Semantically, however, it is an error: you should seek to avoid relying on details of the moved-from object's state, other than it being 'valid'.